# conflicted package does not shows the conflict with base R function

Tags: r

For example this code:

```
library(conflicted)

library(geepack)
library(PairedData)
library(Matrix)

timeorder <- rep(1:5, 6)
tvar <- timeorder + rnorm(length(timeorder))
idvar <- rep(1:6, each=5)
uuu <- rep(rnorm(6), each=5)
yvar <- 1 + 2*tvar + uuu + rnorm(length(tvar))
simdat <- data.frame(idvar, timeorder, tvar, yvar)

mod1 <- geeglm(yvar~tvar, id=idvar, data=simdat, corstr="ar1")

summary(mod1)
```

output:

```
Error: [conflicted] `summary` found in 2 packages.
Either pick the one you want with `::` 
* Matrix::summary
* PairedData::summary
Or declare a preference with `conflict_prefer()`
* conflict_prefer("summary", "Matrix")
* conflict_prefer("summary", "PairedData")
```

In fact there are 3 summary functions here: `base::summary`, `Matrix::summary` and `PairedData::summary`. But only `Matrix::summary` and `PairedData::summary` are reported.

**Question:** Is it bug or there is any solution for it?

Comment: @joran Can you please explain more? Do you mean that: if I use `summary()` on S3 object it will automatically use `base::summary` but if I will use `summary()` on S4 object than I need to choose between those two?

Comment: This is more a ticket item on the authors' repo which I see you [posted](https://github.com/r-lib/conflicted/issues/47).